# sql запрос с дистинктом

Tags: sql

имеется таблица tbl. где-либо на другой стороне запущен сервис, который с неким интервалом времени добавляет в таблицу новую запись.

пример:

3 поля varA varchar, intB integer, timeC time

5 записей

'value', 1, 19-00
'value', 2, 19-01
'value', 2, 19-02
'value', 3, 19-03
'value', 2, 19-04

необходимо получить только те записи, в которых значение второго поля изменилось, в том числе и на значение, которое было когда-либо ранее.

В данном примере получаем:

первая запись

во второй записи значение изменилось с 1 на 2, она должна попасть в резалтсет

в третьей записи значение не изменилось, она в резалтсет попасть НЕ должна

в четвёртой записи изменилось с 2 на 3, в резалтсет

в пятой изменилось с 3 обратно на 2 (2 уже было ранее), по условиям задачи эта запись ДОЛЖНА попасть в резалтсет

Итого получаем, что resultset должен состоять из 4 записей

'value', 1, 19-00
'value', 2, 19-01
'value', 3, 19-03
'value', 2, 19-04

могу придумать только пройти это курсором, но хотелось бы селект. Мне не нравятся курсоры, я считаю их медленными

Comment: Это для пользователей ruSO специально задачка, чтоб не сидели без дела?

Comment: Какова логика выборки? Почему должно быть именно 4? Исходных записей всегда 5? А если будет 100?

Comment: да логика понятна, некий сервис пишет в БД по одной записи каждую минуту, необходимо выдать не все записи поголовно, а только те, где что-то (второе поле) изменилось. В том числе и изменилось на значение, которое уже было когда-то раньше. 5 записей для примера, ну может быть и 100

Comment: Прокомментируйте каждую строчку result set'а с причиной, по которой она в него попала.

Comment: целиком переписал, я думаю, так логика понятнее

Comment: добавить поле с `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и выбирать толкьо измененные данные за определенный промежуток времени?

Comment: Какой диалект? Для SQL Server есть довольно простое решение через outer apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tbl t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 intB FROM #tbl t2 WHERE t2.timeC<t.timeC ORDER BY t2.timeC desc) flt
WHERE flt.intB<>t.intB OR flt.intB IS null
```

Для каждой записи берём предыдущую по времени, если значение изменилось или предыдущей записи нет (первая запись) - выводим.

Comment: никогда не слышал про outer apply, пойду почитаю. в оракл тоже такое есть?

Comment: Если верить гуглу - начиная с 12с. С Oracle не работал, так что точно не скажу. https://emrahmeteen.wordpress.com/2015/12/24/oracle-sql-lateral-cross-apply-outer-apply/

Comment: да, мне очень понравилось это решение. как я понял APPLY соединяет таблицы построчно. я пытался что-то подобное написать через join'ы, не получилось

Answer (score 3):

MS SQL, Oracle, Postresql и другие СУБД поддерживающие оконные функции и в частности функцию lag() возвращающую значение из предыдущей строки:

```
select * from(
  select  varA, intB, timeC, lag(intB) over(order by timeC) old_b
    from tbl
  ) A 
 where intB!=old_b or old_b is null
```

Если в вашей версии SQL оконные функции есть, а функции `LAG()` нет, то вместо нее вы можете воспользоваться, например, `avg(intB) over(order by timeC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`, т.е. получить среднее значение предыдущей и текущей строки, которое будет равно числу в текущей строке если в предыдущей было такое же.

MySQL к сожалению не поддерживает оконные функции, зато поддерживает переменные:

```
select * from(
  select  varA, intB, timeC, @old_b old_b, @old_b:=intB xx
    from tbl,(select @old_b:=-1) A
   order by timeC
  ) A 
 where intB!=old_b
```

Comment: очень интересно, но на устаревших БД этой функции ещё нет

Comment: @user211576 На устаревших это каких ? Можно придумать и другие способы, если есть другие оконные функции, то можно использовать их, например first_value, last_value или даже обычную avg(), просто задав размер окна минус одна запись от текущей. Так же можно явно выбрать предыдущую запись отдельным подзапросом в списке выборки (и outer apply для этого не нужен). Но все способы зависят от конкретной СУБД и версии (даже выборка предыдущей, ведь в старых версиях часто и order by нельзя задать в подзапросе). Если бы вы в вопросе их указали я бы написал запрос под нужную вам версию.

Comment: у меня вот на SQL Server 2012 не работает, хотя MSDN пишет, что поддерживается с 2012

Comment: @user211576 А она точно на нее ругается и как именно ?

Comment: @user211576 Написал в ответе замену, уж AVG у вас обязан быть. надеюсь средства указания размера окна то же.

Comment: теперь "неправильный синтаксис около конструкции 'ROWS'"

Comment: @user211576 Ну значит не судьба воспользоваться оконными функциями. Другие варианты лень расписывать, тем более вам уже другой подходящий ответ дали. Для общего случая можно было бы вынести то что вам написали в outer apply в подзапрос в сипске выборки, получили бы то самое предыдущее значение, которое потом можно сверять или вообще вынести его в позапрос not exists.

Answer (score -3):

Попробуйте использовать триггеры.

Comment: имеете в виду на инсерт повесить? нет, я думаю медленновато. и в данном случае УЖЕ есть таблица